# Discussions on edit review

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits

Recently I made an [accepted edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10564334) and the summary that I wrote was not verbose enough or descriptive. All I intended to do was to improve the readability of the question as the user was new and didn't know how to frame a question properly or edit with proper codes, he wrote his test code in comments section.

Later I got a response from a reviewer,

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

which could be understood as it seems that i have added something extra to the question, but in fact I didn't put anything extra, I just picked up code from the OP's comment box and pasted it well formatted in the question.

I really wanted to convey this to the reviewer but how can I do it now? If we could have a comments sections to discuss why we did that, may be I could have solved this misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4):

The original post was awful, though looking at that edit, there are some minor problems:

- When adding text or code from comments posted by the OP, please mention in the edit description that you included post from a comment. Otherwise the reviewers might think that you are adding random text out of the blue. Likely,  this was the reason for the reject.
- *Italic* should be used for emphasis only.
- Quote formatting should be used to quote *someone else*. It should not be used for emphasis or headlines.

Comment: Point well taken.

Answer (score 2):

Don't over think about it. While your edit was rejected by one user, it was approved by others.

I advise you to take more time when you describe your edits, specially when they're not trivial. It's probably that the reviewer who rejected your edit *didn't* notice that you copied OP's comment to the body of the post and thought that you were adding code on your own, this explains the reject reason.

I really think you should move on, things like that happen.

Comment: Thanks, I was not worried about being rejected or accepted but every person should be given a chance to explain why he did so. The point of asking it here, is to know what would be apt to do in such a situation.(Don't mind my poor English)